# how to set MIDI sound pan?

Tags: java, javasound

Can anyone please suggest me how to set panning for a MIDI sound. I am using java MIDI synthesis and can make it sound. But I want the sound to pan from left to right speakers. I did google but it seemed not to clear to me much? Here the example of code I am working on:

```
Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();

synthesizer.open();

MidiChannel channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[0];

Soundbank soundbank = synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank();

synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);

channel.programChange(0,instrument);
channel.noteOn(60,200);`
```

I am very grateful for any help.
Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MIDI spec](http://www.planetoftunes.com/sequence/midispec.html), panning is controlled by Control Change message number 10. This is the "coarse" value (7 bits of precision) but apparently the "fine" 14-bit version (control change 42) is [likely to be ignored](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midispec/pan.htm) by real devices.

Knowing this, you should be able to use the `controlChange(int, int)` method in the [JavaSound MidiChannel API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiChannel.html#controlChange%28int,%20int%29) to control your panning:

```
final int PAN_CONTROLLER = 10; 
// Pan to Center:
channel.controlChange(PAN_CONTROLLER, 64);

// Pan hard left:
channel.controlChange(PAN_CONTROLLER, 0);

// Pan hard right:
channel.controlChange(PAN_CONTROLLER, 127);

// "Active stereo", Jimi-Hendrix-style
// sweep from almost-full left to almost-full right:
for (int position = 8; position < 127; position += 8) {
    channel.controlChange(PAN_CONTROLLER, position);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```